# How to set breakepoint in windbg when some string seen in stack?

Tags: reverse-engineering, windbg

I want to trace an executable file, loading a lot of dll. I know that this exe file, open a .txt file for reading some of the element. I want to know which function does that. as there are a lot of dll I can't trace each dll's functions to find that. so I want to find a way to set a break-point on point that some '.txt' where seen in the stack to find the function which open or work with the '.txt' file.
Is there anyway to do that?
In other world, Is there any way to set break-point if some known value is passed to an unknown function?

Comment: I would take a look at Rohitab API Monitor http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor. Add all the functions that open a file to the list of traced functions, like OpenFile, ReadFile, ReadFileEx, ...

Comment: Not that I know of but perhaps easier might be to remove all rights to the .txt file and break on the exception trying to read it.

Comment: if you revoke permissions possibly it could fail on create before read. procmon add filter path = filepath should yield a better result apimonitor can fail if the app calls sysenter directly

Comment: +1 @ blabb. Use ProcMon to find the exact stack trace of the specific call you're interested in. Then debug/reverse/whatever it.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set a breakpoint on CreateFileA CreateFileW and inspect the filename parameter to determine if it's the one dealing with the txt file you're interested in. You should also be able to set an automatic breakpoint for every time a new library gets loaded, if you'd like to inspect any loaded modules.